# $rootScope goes out of sync with $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

http://plnkr.co/edit/s64HhVM4b3U5CaMmxcYu?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []).
  run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.foo='bar';
    $rootScope.o={firstName:'john'};
  });

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.copyProp=function(){
    $scope.o.firstName='Fred';
  }
    $scope.copyObj=function(){
    $scope.o={firstName:'Jack'};
  }
      $scope.copyVar=function(){
    $scope.foo='test';
  }
});
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here, if I copy an objects property it stays in sync with root. If I copy the object it goes 'out of sync' the variable doesn't work at all.  Am I correct to assume everything outside the redbox is the rootscope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rootScope.o={firstName:'john'};
...
$scope.o.firstName='Fred';
```

Until now, `$scope` has no property `o`. So when you access `$scope.o` JavaScript looks for `o` in the parent scope up to the root scope until it finds `o`. At this point `$scope.o` **is** `$rootScope.o`. They are not synced, they are the same.

```
$scope.o={firstName:'Jack'};
```

Now `$scope` gets its own property `o`, that is independent from `$rootScope.o`. Consequently `$scope.o.firstName='Fred';` does not change `$rootScope.o`. They have nothing to do with each other.